# creating a common function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a dropdown in react using the output which i get from the below code

markets is an array similar to this

```
[{
  "mkt_id" : 54,
  "mkt_code" : "NZ",
  "mkt_description" : "NZ"
}, {
  "mkt_id" : 55,
  "mkt_code" : "JP",
  "mkt_description" : "JP"
} ];

markets.map(function (country) {
    marketMap.push({
      "label": country.mkt_description,
      "value": String(country.mkt_code)
    })
  })
```

I want to put the above code in a common function in reactjs as I am going to repeat the same for around 10 dropdowns. I am not sure how to pass the values description and mkt_code as argument to this common function which i am creating as these are the two parameters which will keep changing for all the dropdowns.

Comment: Are the markets going to change in different dropdown ? If yes then create an utility function that takes markets as parameter. If not then create a closure that takes markets once and return a new function mapping over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mapArrayToSomethingElse (arr, labelKey, valueKey) {
   return markets.map((country) => ({
     label: country[labelKey],
     value: String(country[valueKey])
   }))
}
```

you now need to provide the `labelKey` and the `valueKey` that you want for each dropdown

Comment: this will work only for one dropdown but the problem is for other dropdowns. The value(eg mkt_description and mkt_code) in the parameter will keep changing for other dropdowns.. is there a way to handle this

Comment: Will those values be a part of the object present in the array ?? Or they can be anything and not present in the array at all ?

Comment: they are values part of the array

Comment: edited the answer, look through it and let me know if it does your work or not